# How to get useful feedback/bug reports from users

Tags: usability, users, bugs

I'm sure most webmasters have recived a mail like this:

> Creating [insert item here] is not
>   working!

When you check it out there is no general problem with the function but rather the user has discovered an edge case. Almost every mail I get is like this and in the long run it gets a bit annoying to always have to ask the user for more information.

Is there anything I can do to get my users provide more useful feedback? Right now I have a mailto: for the webmaster mail in the page footer. I was thinking of changing this so that they have to report through a form on the site.

Anyone got any experience with this? Do you get better/more reports by having a feedback form instead of giving the users the email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done both before.  The key is to make as short of a list as possible for them to describe the issue. If you give them a 20 question form to fill out they will be lost.

Your best bet is answers questions for them. For instance you can scrape the browser version, OS, screen resolution, etc from the browser when they click submit so they don't have to enter it.  Then all you need to know is the info they put into the page and what they clicked in what order.  If you allow them to enter a screen shot file that could go a long way since many users now how to do that and sometimes a picture is worth a 1,000 words.

Comment: So was it worth the effort to implement? Did you get better feedback by using a form instead of email?

Comment: @Mikael - Yes just make sure to keep it simple.  Spending 100 hours to make some awesome form that no one uses is a waste.  Just keep track of the most important stuff and slowly build it out.